# Importing module from command prompt is working but not working from spyder

Tags: python

I'm using python 3.6 on windows 7.I was trying to learn python import for user defined module following the steps mentioned in [here](https://www.codementor.io/sheena/python-path-virtualenv-import-for-beginners-du107r3o1)

While I'm doing import `my_funcs`, After creating `my_funcs.py`, using python interpreter in command prompt from the directory of `my_funcs.py` then it's working fine but while I'm doing same by creating another python scrip & saved that script in `my_funcs.py` directory & running it through anaconda spyder then it's throwing error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_funcs'
```

Please guide me to solve this issue

Comment: At a guess, the active directory of Spyder doesn't match the directory of the script you are running. Check in top right of the IDE.

Comment: Thank you @roganjosh.It's working now.